# How to connect to MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

I've bought a server from CloudAtCost.com and all the information it gives me about my server is Server ID, IP Address, Netmask, and Gateway. I can SSH in just fine, but I can't get MySQL Workbench to connect to it. I've tried both Standard (TCP/IP) and Standard TCP/IP Over SSH.

Comment: Is MySQL actually installed on your server?

Comment: Yes, I can start it on the command line.

Comment: Usually, there's an error message returned that gives an indication of what the problem is. Could be invalid username/password, could be network connections are not enabled, could be DNS reverse lookup is failing, could be port 3306 is not open (blocked by a firewall). So many possibilities. "can't get MySQL workbench to connect to it" is too vague to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've been trying different things and they give different errors so it's hard to give that info. Let me try and put some more detail into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using "user" as my username when I needed to use "root".

Answer (score 0):

MySQL server needs to be running.

Network connections need to be enabled.

You need to know what port MySQL is running on (default is 3306).

If reverse DNS lookup has not been disabled, MySQL has to be able to resolve IP address to hostname.

MySQL User has to be created and assigned a password, a username and host, host is either the specific host connecting or (less secure) a '%' wildcard for host. If DNS lookups are disabled, host will be an IP address.

Connections to the MySQL port (by default it's 3306) may be "blocked" by firewall...

There are a *lot* of possible reasons.

---

When we can't connect, there's usually a MySQL error message that indicates the kind of problem encountered.

---

But, my preference would be to *only* allow IP connections from 127.0.0.1. (We always turn off reverse dns lookups on our MySQL servers.)

I'd use ssh port forwarding (tunneling). Choose a port to use on your local machine, e.g. 13306, and configure SSH to "forward" connections to that port through the ssh connection...

You can configure that in the .ssh/config for the specific remote server, e.g.

```
Host remoteserver
  LocalForward 13306 localhost:3306
```

You'd need to first ssh to the remoteserver, and keep that session open.

Then on your local machine, MySQL Workbench would connect to `localhost` port `13306`.  On the MySQL server side, that will be seen as coming from IP address 127.0.0.1,

Obviously, you'd need to have a user created, e.g.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO myusername@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'
```

And grant appropriate privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mysql Workbench>Server Status>Note down the port number
and give hostname as localhost:your port number,usually its 3306